# Meaning of ember init 'Yndh'

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

What does `Yndh` mean when you run `ember init`?

I get this:

```
installing
[?] Overwrite .editorconfig? (Yndh)
```

`Yn` is *yes* and *no*. Anyone know what `dh` means?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Turning @DamienMATHIEU's comment into a community answer:

`Yndh` stands for **Yes**, **no**, **diff**, **help**.